# arm cache flush vs non-cache memory block performance for dma

Tags: caching, memory, arm

If we want to prepare some data in memory for external device(like DMA)

which performance is better?

1.
set the memory address as cacheable, write the data to the memory block, then flush the memory block

2.
set the memory address as non-cache, write the data to the memory block directly

is the performance result close? 
any other conditions can impact the result?
like the cache line size, memory block size? cache setting write back/write through? architecture?

thanks

Comment: Performance of what, exactly? Either way, the DMA operation is going to take as long as it takes to read from DRAM, and the CPU/cache system is going to take at least as long as it takes to write that much data to DRAM. The efficiency tradeoffs between the two approaches mostly depend on the larger-scale usage pattern (i.e. how often the buffer is read vs. written by each agent involved), and for certain situations there may also be correctness concerns that trump any performance consideration. In short, there is no general answer.

Comment: It depends on the CPU memory usage.  If you have unbanked/shadowed video RAM that directly DMAs, then a flush on the HBLANK/VBLANK maybe perfect.  Many blitting operations will be perform with read-modify-write by the CPU.  However, if you don't do many operation of the RAM w CPU, then the cache-less might be better; for instance feeding a motor PWM with pre-calced data.  Ie, just two cases where either is right.

Comment: Not enough info, depends on your definition of performance, what the hardware looks like (arm is not an answer to that), dma design, memory design, cache design, etc.  The only real answer is just try it, the only way to know for your particular system with your software.

Comment: DMA is nothing more than logic that generates bus transactions for you, what bus, what kind of transactions, how priority is managed, etc is very specific to your chip/system.  When you say prepare, I assume write, the cache should not affect this as it is mostly for reads, but it may have a write buffer on the back or write through, so you should fiddle with those things.  If you do this from code the size of the transfers may or may not matter, super simple to test.  basically try stms of 2, 4, 6 and 8 registers in an honest and accurately timed test to see if any perform better

Comment: aligned addresses of course.

Comment: oh , sorry about the definition of performance, i am curious about the speed of writing back to main memory like DRAM. i am not sure about enable cache or not, which one can have better speed for writing data into  memory.